# The completeness in Banach-Steinhaus theorem and open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

For Banach-Steinhaus theorem and open mapping theorem, we require the space be complete, that means that even two metrics (one translate invariant while another not) with same topology may have different result, so I want to know what's the principle behind it.

Comment: What is the principle behind what?

Comment: In proof of both theorems we use strongly the Baire's theorem, wich states that every complete space is a Baire space.

Comment: @BBVM Baire's theorem just depends on the topology of that space, so if the topology is the same, it doesn't matter